# What prompt is sh using when you type sh into Terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, environment-variables, ps1

When using the default PS1 prompt that MAC OS/Terminal comes with, when you type sh you get a new style prompt.

```
station-4:~ user$ sh
sh-3.2$
```

When you export your own PS1, this functionality goes away.  You type sh and you still get the PS1 prompt you specified.  Why is this?

```
station-4:~ user$ export PS1=">>>"
>>>sh
>>>
```

Comment: Try `which sh` to see what your shell is, and check the result for symlinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Export" is the key word. I don't have a Mac myself, but my guess is that its `bashrc` file doesn't *export* `$PS1`, merely sets it, so that `bash` itself sees the variable but doesn't push it to the environment of new processes. (*bash* is the default shell used by OS X.)

You can use `printenv PS1`, `env | grep ^PS1` or `declare -p PS1` to find out whether a variable is part of the environment. (You will see `declare -x` if the variable is exported, `declare --` otherwise.)